# On macOS, how can I find the app's path which opens with “open” command?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, environment-variables

In macOS, one of the options to open an application via "open" command would be like so:

```
$ open -a "Google Chrome"
$ open -a "GIMP"
```

But I realized that the command above **works even if the apps weren't in `/Applications` nor `~/Applications` directory**.

So, "how can I get the path of this app" using a command line?

I tried to use the `find` command and search the whole machine, but I thought that there would be an easier way to find it.

The reason is that I need to access the bin file inside the ".app" directory like below:

```
$ /path/to/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP-bin --help-all
```

Since the command below doesn't seem to parse the arguments.

```
$ open -a "GIMP" --args --help-all
```

---

- macOS HighSierra (OSX 10.13.5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found another answer.

**This script won't launch the app while checking the paths** like the [Applescript one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618485/8367711).

Since it just `grep`s the [`lsregister`](https://ss64.com/osx/lsregister.html)'s dump result, it might not be as accurate as the Applescript,  but so far it seems to work.

**Script:**

An alternative way to find the application path with `bash` (**without using AppleScript**) using [`lsregister`](https://ss64.com/osx/lsregister.html) command.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# findApp.sh
# ==========
NAME_APP=$1
PATH_LAUNCHSERVICES="/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister"
${PATH_LAUNCHSERVICES} -dump | grep -o "/.*${NAME_APP}.app" | grep -v -E "Caches|TimeMachine|Temporary|/Volumes/${NAME_APP}" | uniq
```

**Usage:**

```sh
$ ./findApp.sh "Google Chrome"
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
$ ./findApp.sh GIMP
/Volumes/External_HDD/Applications/GIMP/GIMP_v2.8/GIMP.app
```

- REF: [Applescript: Get path to .app without opening it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639490/8367711)
   @ Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer.

**Use `osascript` command** to get the application's path associated with the system.

**Shell:**

```sh
$ osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to application "GIMP")'
/Volumes/External_HDD/Applications/GIMP/GIMP_v2.8/GIMP.app/
```

or

```sh
$ open -a "GIMP"
$ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to POSIX path of (file of process "GIMP" as alias)'
/Volumes/External_HDD/Applications/GIMP/GIMP_v2.8/GIMP.app/
```

**Sample script:**

Sample shell-script that fetches the GIMP's binary and makes it work as CLI application. (Tested on macOS HighSierra OSX 10.13.6)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PATH_GIMP=`osascript -e 'POSIX path of (path to application "GIMP")'`

echo `$PATH_GIMP/Contents/MacOS/GIMP-bin --help-all`
```

---

- reference:

  - [How do I find the path to a program in Terminal?](https://superuser.com/a/570120) | SuperUser @ StackExchange
  - [AppleScriptのファイル参照にまつわるメモ](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/zariganitosh/20100924/apple_script_alias_posix_file) @ ザリガニが見ていた...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the quick way to find out where an app is installed is to run:

```
which <app_name>
> /location/where/running/from
```

In the event the returned file is a `symlink`, run the following:

```
readlink /location/where/running/from
> /the/real/source/where/running/from
```

In the event you are dealing with a python app, the following might also be useful:

```
pip show <app_name>

> Name: ...
> Version: ...
> ...
> Location: /location/of/the/app
```

Comment: this didnt work for me, it only showed terminal commands, not GUI mac apps.

Answer (score 0):

The `open` command on macOS won't provide that information. But since you presumably know you are running on macOS just do the test yourself. That is, test whether */Applications/GIMP.app* or *~/Applications/GIMP.app* exists. The reason your attempt to use `--args --help-all` doesn't work is that the app is not run within the context of your shell with its stdout and stderr streams inherited from your shell. It is run as a child of the "init" process. So the `--help-all` argument doesn't do anything useful since the process exits without displaying any information in your shell (which assumes GIMP isn't already running). The `open` command is the wrong tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: `"It is run as a child of the 'init' process."` <- A-ha! I got it. That's why I can't parse the arguments via `open` command to GIMP in my case. I tried to dig directories but a bunch of  _GIMP.app_ with a different version I found. Like `/Volumes/EXT_HDD/GIMP_Vxx/GIMP.app`. But I want the current associated one. So there's no command to find out where the default application is placed in? Like some kind of POSIX path env settings?

Answer (score 0):

It is just easy by checking the process name with `ps aux`. For instance, when my Atom (a text editor app) is opened, I see that the actual application is launched from `/Applications`

```
> ps aux | grep Atom

junji            63388   0.3  1.4 41357168 460532   ??  S     3:46PM   0:02.96 /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom
```